# How to remove the section name of \printglossary?

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, glossaries

I added a heading for my glossary with `\addcontentsline`.

However the `\printglossary` command still creates an additional section heading.

How can this be removed?

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
% Glossary
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Glossar}
\newpage
\printglossary[style=altlist]

% Acronyms
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
\deftranslation[to=German]{Acronyms}{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
\newpage
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=dontgroup]
```

Comment: It is possible to redefine `\printglossary` to make a chapter heading instead of `\section`. See, for example, the `\setglossarysection{<name>}` function or `section=...` key-value (p 33 of the [`glossaries`](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.pdf)). Could you provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) rather than a code snippet?

Comment: `\addcontentsline` followed by `\newpage` is clearly wrong. Say `\setglossarysection{chapter}` and remove the `\addcontentsline` declarations.

Comment: This has helped me! Thanks to egreg. Thanks also to the other proposals! \setglossarysection{chapter} \printglossary

Answer (score 2):

Your code example is far from being a MWE, but I guess you are using the `glossaries` package with the options `toc` and `section` within a `book` class. When loading this package with the `toc` option the entries in the ToC are generated, while the `section` option makes the glossaries as sections. Therefore, change the package loading to

```
\usepackage[acronym,toc]{glossaries}  % no section option
```

and print the glossaries without the `\addcontentsline` with

```
\cleardoublepage
\printglossary[style=altlist]
\deftranslation[to=German]{Acronyms}{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
\cleardoublepage
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=dontgroup]
```

Comment: I think you missed a comma in the package option list. (`acronym,toc`)

Answer (score -1):

the previous answer is incorrect, at least in the glossaries version supplied with Ubuntu 13 there is no such option "acronymtoc" neitherstyle=dontgroup. This is also not documented in http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Glossary#Using_glossaries.
You simply need to add "nonumberlist" option to usepackage.

```
\usepackage[nonumberlist]{glossaries}
```